# Django QuerySets - with a class method

Tags: django, django-models

Below is a stripped down model and associated method.  I am looking for a simple way upon executing a query to get all of the needed information in a single answer without having to re-query everything.  The challenge here is the `value` is dependent upon the signedness of value_id.

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property_definition = models.ForeignKey(PropertyDefinition)
    owner = models.IntegerField()
    value_id = models.IntegerField()

    def get_value(self):
        if self.value_id < 0: return PropertyLong.objects.get(id=-self.value_id)
        else: return PropertyShort.objects.get(id=self.value_id)
```

Right now to get the "value" I need to do this:

```
object = Property.objects.get(property_definition__name="foo")
print object.get_value()
```

Can someone provide a cleaner way to solve this or is it "good" enough?  Ideally I would like to simply just do this.

```
object = Property.objects.get(property_definition__name="foo")
object.value
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)?

Comment: Hey Daniel!  Thanks for replying - No I hadn't considered it.  In reading the docs It states that I should use (typically) a PositiveIntegerField. How do I deal with the signedness of this?

Comment: Well my point was that you wouldn't need to use that positive/negative logic, as you would use the `content_type` to distinguish between your long and short properties.

Comment: Now I'm lost (go figure) - I was thinking about adding this '    value_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='value')
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')'  I think you had another idea?

Comment: Maybe I got this wrong, but doesn't every `Property` have exactly one `PropertyLong` it belongs to?

Comment: Hey lazerscience - No only if it's negative..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this is a bad design. You can use the builtin [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) decorator for your method to make it act as a property.

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property_definition = models.ForeignKey(PropertyDefinition)
    owner = models.IntegerField()
    value_id = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.value_id < 0: return PropertyLong.objects.get(id=-self.value_id)
        else: return PropertyShort.objects.get(id=self.value_id)
```

This would enable you to do what you'd ideally like to do: `Property.objects.get(pk=1).value`

But I would go as far as to call this "cleaner". ;-)

You could go further and write your own [custom model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) by extending `django.models.Field` to hide the nastiness in your schema behind an API. This would at least give you the API you want now, so you can migrate the nastiness out later.

That or the Generic Keys mentioned by others. Choose your poison...

Answer (score 1):

this is a bad design. as Daniel Roseman said, take a look at generic foreign keys if you must reference two different models from the same field.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: I'm with you on that! This is a legacy design I'm trying to massage to make it work. I don't understand Daniels comment on the use of 'content_type' to distinguish between the two properties.  That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: as the documentation that I linked to says, you will create a foreign key referencing the table that stores content types. they call this foreign key "generic". another auxiliary field that must accompany this foreign key will contain the id of the object that has this content type. your long and short properties will have different content types because they are modeled by different models. this is how you will be able to tell which table the id stored in the auxiliary field points to. I personally would just use two non-generic foreign key fields. one for each property.

Answer (score 0):

[Model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance) could be used since value is not a Field instance.